# ListModel in qml, getting objects from model

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListModel that I fill in the following way:

```
property ListModel projects: ListModel {}
property Project currentProject : null

function initialization(){
    var comp = Qt.createComponent("Project.qml");
    var object = comp.createObject(parent,{});
    projects.append(object);
    currentProject = projects.get(0)

}
Component.onCompleted: root.initialization();
```

And I have a error in `currentProject = projects.get(0)` line.
Error text:

```
main.qml:14: Error: Cannot assign QObject* to Project_QMLTYPE_0*
```

Comment: as workaround, i suggest to change `property` to `property QtObject currentProject : null`

Comment: Thanks, It Is usable, but  this looks terrible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you append your `Project` object to the ListModel, it is the properties of `Project` object being added to the ListModel (as ListModel roles), not the `Project` object itself. So, when you use `ListModel.get()`, the return object is just a object (QObject* to be exact) with the ListModel roles as properties, but not the `Project` object.

To be more simple, ListModel is not a container for your `Project` object. It just store the properties of your `Project` object.

Comment: It interesting!Thanks.
By the way,сan you help with the choice of container?

Comment: It is better you use the [Data Model](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qdeclarativemodels.html) design to keep data and display your UI. If your `Project` is a UI, make it become the delegate of a view (ListView, Repeater, etc) then insert data to the ListModel. If you just want to keep data, put it in JavaScript array and store in [variant](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-variant.html). You also might be interest in [QML list type](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-list.html)